# What are the steps for a beginner to electronics to get custom PCBs made for a simple adapter?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I need to make an adapter between two 14-pin board-to-board connectors, one being a [MicroMatch](http://www.te.com/catalog/minf/en/439) and the other being a [JMC](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=147).

What is the most straightforward way to get a PCB designed and ordered so that I only need to solder those connectors?

P.S.: I'm a computer science guy, so please excuse my ignorance :)

Comment: I've never used them, but you might have a look at [ExpressPCB](http://www.expresspcb.com/index.htm). They offer small quantities and free layout software (for their boards only, I think).

Answer (score 6):

**Step 1:** Obtain a PCB design software and get familiar with it. Free options include [CadSoft Eagle Light Edition](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/download-eagle/freeware/) and [KiCAD EDA](http://www.kicad-pcb.org/display/KICAD/KiCad+EDA+Software+Suite). Many others exist, but these two might be easiest to find basic tutorials for.

**Step 2:** Find the footprints for the connectors involved from the respective datasheets, or, if the manufacturers provide downloadable footprint files for your selected software, use those.

**Step 3:** Create a PCB layout with the two connectors, and PCB traces running between respective pins on the two footprints from above. Keep note of mirroring of footprints / pin numbers due to the connector being on the upper or lower layer of the PCB.

**Step 4:** Convert the PCB layout to Gerber format and order the PCBs from one of the many small-order PCB services, such as [ITeadStudio](http://imall.iteadstudio.com/open-pcb/pcb-prototyping/im120418001.html), [OshPark](http://oshpark.com/) or other prototyping / hobbyist friendly PCB services. Personal opinion: Those two work out the cheapest for small orders of small boards.

Wait for delivery, solder the connectors, and offer the spare boards to whoever wants them.

Comment: I have been very pleased with iteadstudio, as mentioned by @Andino.

Comment: Oshpark's PCBs are probably better for beginner solderers, since the gold-plating makes them wet with solder *very* easily.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Very true. iTeadStudio offers only HASL finish at the basic price, not ENIG. Also OshPark PCBs are a really neat purple color. :-)

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - THERE ARE NO OTHER COLOURS. THERE IS ONLY PURPLE.

Comment: @ConnorWolf That's why I like them!

Comment: Though EAGLE is a german acronym "Einfach Anzuwendender Graphischer LayoutEditor" (easy to use graphical layout editor), it's not that intuitive. This is because its concept is older than Windows/Mac and differs from their concept. However, EAGLE is widely used __and many PCB manufacturers accept EAGLE board files directly__. So, you usually don't have to care about Gerber files.

Comment: If Eagle or KiCAD is too much, there's also [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/) that's a lot more beginner friendly. I used that for a long time before learning KiCAD.